# Model.findOne() is returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Model.findOne() is returning null even if the valid collection is present in the respective Model

```
app.post("/fleetManagement", (req, res) => {

  const requestedDriverID = req.body.driverId;
  console.log(requestedDriverID);

  Driver.findOne({
      _id: requestedDriverID
  }, function(err, requestedDriverResult) {
      console.log(requestedDriverResult);
      res.render("fleetManagement", {
          reqDriver: requestedDriverResult
      });
  });
})
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCLeW.png)
[Collection in Driver Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZTZm.png)

Check out the Output and Collection of Driver Model

Comment: Are you sure that `err` doesn't have an error?

Comment: yaaa
i even checked it :(

Comment: Did you create the existing documents in the collection with the same Mongoose configuration, or is it an existing collection that you are now creating a Mongoose schema for?

Comment: i've added  few fields from mongo compass manually and _id was generated automatically

Comment: @Tharun_bp okay, let me put it another way: what's the name of the collection that you're showing the documents from, and *are you sure* that your schema/model is using the same collection (don't assume it does)?

Answer (score 0):

Try convert requestedDriverID to ObjectId(requestedDriverID)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, an answer should actually be an *answer* in which you have confidence. "Try xyz" indicates that you don't know whether that will help with the problem.

Comment: No use, It's still returning null

Comment: Pleae read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the _id input to [ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).
Here's the updated code for your reference:

```
app.post("/fleetManagement",(req, res)=>{

const requestedDriverID = req.body.driverId;
console.log( requestedDriverID);

Driver.findOne({_id: ObjectId(requestedDriverID)  }, function(err, requestedDriverResult){
console.log(requestedDriverResult);
  res.render("fleetManagement", {
    reqDriver:requestedDriverResult
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I didn't get it can u help me plzz :(
what should i change in code

Comment: You need to change requestedDriverID to ObjectId(requestedDriverID).